# How can I change #define

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

How can I change #define TRIAL to #define PREMIUM, when user enter some register key for example.

Thanks.

```
//#define TRIAL
#define PREMIUM

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Attributes
{
    [Obsolete("This is an old class. Use new class instead!")] 
    class Test
    {
        [Conditional("TRIAL")]
        void Trial()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trial");
        }

        [Conditional("PREMIUM")]
        void Release()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PREMIUM");
        }
......................................
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be misunderstanding preprocessor directives. You should store this kind of information somehow encrypted on the user's machine and load it into variables, or better yet, release two versions with the option to upgrade. That will be more stable and secure.

If you choose to take that approach, that's where you can use preprocessor directives to compile a different version of your libraries and code for each release of the program.

Answer (score 1):

#define is compile-time directive, so you can't use it... Instead, you should use the good old if:

```
class Test
{
    void DoAction() {
      if(trial) { Console.WriteLine("Trial"); }
      else { Console.WriteLine("PREMIUM");
    }
}
```